# When resetting password of Apache IoTDB, why error reported "connection refused"?

Tags: apache-iotdb, iotdb, changepasswordtemplate

Msg: 713: All retry failed due to: net.sf.cglib.core.CodeGenerationException: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException-->java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)

ALTER USER root SET PASSWORD

I use "ALTER USER root SET PASSWORD" command to reset the password of Apache IoTDB, and an error is reported: "Msg: 713: All retry failed due to: net.sf.cglib.core.CodeGenerationException: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException-->java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused". Has anyone encountered this error before and knows what does "connection refused" means?

Does anyone can deal this problem？ Help please